# Traverse a directory with wildcards - built-in method?

Tags: c#, filesystems, wildcard

I am trying to look for a file `xsd.exe` that can be in one of many places, and select the one with the latest timestamp.  There are many different versions of this file; on my dev system alone I had like 8 different versions, and most if not all looked different from each other.

What I want to do is set an initializer, looking in the common locations, collecting a list of the possible candidates, and then selecting from among them.

I thought I had a pretty elegant method of doing so:

```
var potentialLocations = new[]
    {
        @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\*\Bin\*",
        @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\*\bin",
        @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio*\SDK\*\Bin"
    };

IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();
files = potentialLocations.Aggregate(files,
                                        (current,
                                        potentialLocation) =>
                                        current.Concat(
                                            Directory.GetDirectories(potentialLocation)
                                                    .Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x))
                                                    .SelectMany(x => x.GetFiles("xsd.exe"))));

var file = files
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTimeUtc)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

... but unfortunately, `Directory.GetDirectories` does not like my wildcard patterns; I get an `ArgumentException`: "Illegal characters in path".

Is there a method to traverse these directory structures using wildcards like I've specified?  Or am I going to have to build something custom for this?

Comment: I guess you need to implement the search manually. Look for all the `bin` directories in specified locations, the perform another search there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in method to do this for you, however you could built it.

The GetDirectories method has a search pattern [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can use, but it will only get you part of the way there.  For example, the code below will get you all bin folders under the `Program Files (x86)` folder.

```
var directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Program Files (x86)", @"Bin", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (var dir in directories)
    Console.WriteLine(dir);
```

Or if you just want all Microsoft folders in the `Program Files (x86)`, you could do this:

```
var directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\Program Files (x86)", @"Microsoft*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

foreach (var dir in directories)
    Console.WriteLine(dir);
```

I say it only gets you part of the way there because the GetDirectories override will not let you use a string that contains sub directories like `Microsoft Visual Studio*\SDK\`

If you want to have more fine grained control with multiple wildcards and sub directories, then you will need to parse the string manually and then you can leverage the overrides to search for matches.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thanks.